# Can't see admob in cocos2dx

Tags: android, admob

I'm pretty sure the problem is in here somewhere:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
      // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LayoutParams adParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    addContentView(adView, adParams);
}
```

and yes, the id is initialized correctly.

Comment: You need to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you are calculating the position in adParams. Here's the code I use, which puts the ad at the bottom of the screen:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),                        
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()+getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-110);

adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, “XXXXXX”);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(request);                
addContentView(adView, adParams);
```

Comment: getWidth and getHeight are deprecated, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;


LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight + screenHeight-70);

 // Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
    .build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);


// Adding full screen container
addContentView(adView, adParams);
```